# Can I schedule a Google Cloud Task on the client side to call a cloud function with a payload?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-tasks

I want to make sure I'm thinking about Cloud Tasks right conceptually, and not sure that I am.

The examples I've been looking at seem to trigger a cloud function first that then schedules a task, that then calls a cloud function again.

(Or at least this is what I'm understanding, I could be wrong).

I'd like to set up something so that when a user clicks a button, it schedules a cloud task for some time in the future (anywhere from 1 minute to an hour and half). The cloud task then triggers the cloud function to upload the payload to the db.

I tried to set this up client side but I've been getting the error "You need to pass auth instance to use gRPC-fallback client in browser or other non-Node.js environments."

I don't want the user to have to authenticate if that's what this is saying (not sure why I'd have to do that for my use case).

This is the code that gives that error.

```
const {CloudTasksClient} = require('@google-cloud/tasks');
const client = new CloudTasksClient();


// import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';
//     const {  RemotePlugin } = Plugins;

const scheduleTask = async(seconds) => {
  async function createHttpTask() {

    const project = 'spiral-productivity';
    const queue = 'spiral';
    const location = 'us-west2';
    const url = 'https://example.com/taskhandler';
    const payload = 'Hello, World!';
    const inSeconds = 5;

    // Construct the fully qualified queue name.
    const parent = client.queuePath(project, location, queue);

    const task = {
      httpRequest: {
        httpMethod: 'POST',
        url,
      },
    };

    if (payload) {
      task.httpRequest.body = Buffer.from(payload).toString('base64');
    }

    if (inSeconds) {
      // The time when the task is scheduled to be attempted.
      task.scheduleTime = {
        seconds: inSeconds + Date.now() / 1000,
      };
    }

    // Send create task request.
    console.log('Sending task:');
    console.log(task);
    const request = {parent: parent, task: task};
    const [response] = await client.createTask(request);
    console.log(`Created task ${response.name}`);
  }
  createHttpTask();
  // [END cloud_tasks_create_http_task]

}
```

More recently I set up a service account and download a .json file and all of that. But doesn't this mean my users will have to authenticate?

That's why I stopped. Maybe I'm on the wrong track, but if anyone wants to answer what I need to do to schedule a cloud task from the client side without making the user authenticate, it would be a big help.

As always, I'm happy to improve the question if anything isn't clear. Just let me know, thanks!

Comment: Your understanding is mostly accurate. Cloud Tasks is a way to queue "tasks". The examples are likely using Cloud Functions as an analog for "some app" (a web app) that would be analogous to your Node.js (web) app, i.e. your Node.js app can submit tasks to Cloud Tasks. To access Google Cloud Platform services (e.g. Cloud Tasks), you need to authenticate and authorize. Since your app is the "user" of the GCP services, you're correct in using a Service Account. Service Accounts function as identities for software where the application's users need not be known to GCP.

Comment: @DazWilkin - thanks so it's not every individual user that will need to authenticate, in this case it is just my app that is the 'user'?

Comment: You must implement authorization. Otherwise, the Cloud Tasks service will be abused by anyone on the Internet.

Comment: Yes, exactly. The app is the identity and it operates on behalf of your users. The **only** time (!?) that your Users would need to login to a Google Cloud Platform service is if you want to access your users' data that's stored on GCP e.g. Google Workplace. In this case, Google mandates that your users login and their permission be sought by your app for it to access their data. Since, you're not doing that, you don't need to do any of that. Your app has an identity (the Service Account) but it must authenticate and authorize to GCP so that it is permitted to use e.g. Cloud Tasks.

Comment: @DazWilkin thanks, that's what I was getting confused about. I recently made an app that wrote to google docs so I had to implement the full user auth.

Comment: See [Application Default Credentials](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#auth-cloud-implicit-nodejs) to understand authenticating (code) as a service account. It's very easy. If your Node.js app is itself running on GCP e.g. as a Cloud Function or Cloud Run or App Engine etc., it will run as a Service Account automatically (though it's a good idea to use a specific Service Account for your app even so). Then, it's just a matter of ensuring that the Service Account has suitable roles (permissions) to use e.g. Cloud Tasks (and whatever else it needs access to).

Comment: Exactly! Then you usually need to do so because (Google-managed) user data is protected by Google. There's actually a solution (Domain-wide delegation) where Google Workspace admins can access user data using a Service Account but, let's not go there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Your understanding is mostly accurate. Cloud Tasks is a way to queue "tasks". The examples are likely using Cloud Functions as an analog for "some app" (a web app) that would be analogous to your Node.js (web) app, i.e. your Node.js app can submit tasks to Cloud Tasks. To access Google Cloud Platform services (e.g. Cloud Tasks), you need to authenticate and authorize.

Since your app is the "user" of the GCP services, you're correct in using a Service Account.

See [Application Default Credentials](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#auth-cloud-implicit-nodejs) to understand authenticating (code) as a service account.

**Additionally**, see [Controlling access to webapps](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/authenticating-web-users).